# Rank Stacked Bar Chart by Sum of Subset of Fill Variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

Sample data:

```
set.seed(145)

df <- data.frame(Age=sample(c(1:10),20,replace=TRUE),
                 Rank=sample(c("Extremely","Very","Slightly","Not At All"),
                             20,replace=TRUE),
                 Percent=(runif(10,0,.01)))

df.plot <- ggplot(df,aes(x=Age,y=Percent,fill=Rank))+
           geom_bar(stat="identity")+
           coord_flip()
df.plot
```

Within the ggplot, how can I reorder `x=Age`, by the sum of Ranks "Extremely" and "Very" only?

I tried using the below, without success.

```
df.plot <- ggplot(df,aes(x=reorder(Age,Rank=="Extremely",sum),y=Percent,fill=Rank))+
              geom_bar(stat="identity")+
              coord_flip()
df.plot
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of notes:

1. The way that you are simulating your data does not rule out the possibility that for some ages, all categories are not represented (which is fine), but also that for some ages, some categories are duplicated. I am assuming that this is not true for your real data, so have let this be. Note also that your simulation logic does not produce percentages that add up, although the category names indicate that they should.
2. The way I would do this is to create the ordering of age based on your desired logic, and then pass that order to the `factor` call. This decouples the ordering logic and allows arbitrary ordering logic.

Here is then what I think you are looking for:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

set.seed(145)

# simulate the data
df_foo = data.frame(Age=sample(c(1:10),20,replace=TRUE),
                 Rank=sample(c("Extremely","Very","Slightly","Not At All"),
                             20,replace=TRUE),
                 Percent=(runif(10,0,.01)))

# get the ordering that you are interested in
age_order = df_foo %>% 
  filter(Rank %in% c("Extremely", "Very")) %>% 
  group_by(Age) %>% 
  summarize(SumRank = sum(Percent)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(SumRank)) %>% 
  `[[`("Age")

# in some cases ages do not appear in the order because the 
#   ordering logic does not span all categories
age_order = c(age_order, setdiff(unique(df_foo$Age), age_order))

# make age a factor sorted by the ordering above  
ggplot(df_foo, aes(x = factor(Age, levels = age_order), y = Percent, fill = Rank))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

Which code produces:

[image]

Comment: I was able to produce the needed result, when excluding `age_order = c(age_order, setdiff(unique(df_foo$Age), age_order))` Otherwise, this worked as needed.